# Laravel Save() Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Am newbie in Laravel and have the following code but getting exception ::

// In the models folder, i have this class ::

```
class Game extends Eloquent{

}
```

// In the Routes.php file i have this::

```
Route::get('/tee/me', function(){
    $game = new Game;
    $game->name = 'Assassins Creed';
    $game->description = 'Assassins VS templars';
    $game.save();
});
```

When i run ".........../tee/me" to post to the database i get the following exception::

```
"Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined function save() "
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you have got mistake in provided source ($game.save()). Also, undefined function is pretty clear error, see, what methods Game object (and it's ancestors and traits) posses, save probably won't be one of them.

Comment: @apocalypz The Game class extends Eloquent. So the save() method exist already for the Game class. Isn't that true? Do i still have to declare the save() method again?

Comment: how about visibility ... is it public method ? Also, try some debugger, put breakpoint on game->save and see, where you end ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
$game->save(); and not $game.save();
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer is indeed "->" and not "."